# Arraylist elements starting too much activity

Tags: java, android, listview

I am developing an application, that sends a string array with putStringArrayListExtra. In the second activity I am receiving. The problem, if I send 2 item, 2 activity will open. The second element is on the listview(shows just one), when i click back, there is now the first item. I want the 2 item in the SAME listview. What am I doing wrong?

First activity

```
final int len = thumbnailsselection.length;
            int cnt = 0;
            String selectImages = "";
           // String result = "";
            String ar="";


            for (int i =0; i<len; i++)
            {
                if (thumbnailsselection[i])
                {
                    cnt++;
                    ar = nev[i];
                    selectImages = nev[i] + "|";
                   // List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(selectImages));
                   ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
                    arr.add(selectImages);

                   Intent intent = new Intent(Gallery.this,Upload.class);
                    intent.putStringArrayListExtra("array_list", arr);

                    startActivity(intent);

                    // Log.i("adat","galleri:" + arr);





                }

            }
            if (cnt == 0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Please select at least one image",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {





                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "You've selected Total " + cnt + " image(s).",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    });
```

Second activity

```
ListView listView;

ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();


       // ArrayList<String> arr = (ArrayList<String>)b.getStringArrayList("array_list");
    ArrayList<String> arr = b.getStringArrayList("array_list");
        Log.i("adat","UPLOAD:"+arr);


    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, arr);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
```

Comment: Put your Arraylist declaration outside the for loop. Also Initialize intent & call startActivity() after for loop.

Comment: Put intent `data passing logic` outside the for loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do like below while you are creating new arraylist everytime when you loop thats why you are not getting correct values.

And also take you intent outside the loop too.

```
 ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();
 for (int i =0; i<len; i++){
     if (thumbnailsselection[i]){
         cnt++;
         ar = nev[i];
         selectImages = nev[i] + "|";             
         arr.add(selectImages); 
     } 
 }

Intent intent = new Intent(Gallery.this,Upload.class);
intent.putStringArrayListExtra("array_list", arr);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem. The startActivity needs to be outside the for loop.

Comment: thank you. this works. but when i click back, and if I have 3 items, it wont take me back to activity first, but to the same activity, with the second element, i click once again the back button, then there is the first element on the list.